# Differentiate ambiguous Extensions in Kotlin

Tags: android, generics, range, kotlin

I came upon an issue where the compiler "cannot choose among the following candidates" when I refer to `rng.max` where `rng:IntRange`:

```
inline val <T:Comparable<T>> ClosedRange<T>.max get() = endInclusive   // max of range
inline val <T:Comparable<T>> Iterable<T>.max get():T? = max()  // max element
```

I think this is because an `IntRange` implements both `ClosedRange` and (indirectly through `IntProgression`) `Iterable`.

If I wanted to write a **single extension function** that would apply to **all of** `IntRange`, `LongRange` and `CharRange` (presumably but not necessarily by extending `ClosedRange`), is there any syntax I could add that would unambiguously resolve to `ClosedRange` rather than the similarly-named `Iterable` extension in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is there any syntax I could add that would unambiguously resolve to ClosedRange rather than the similarly-named Iterable extension in this case?

The distinction has to be made by the client in your example with two ambiguous extensions.

Simply tell the compiler which type you want to work with:

```
val intRange = 0..10
(intRange as ClosedRange<Int>).max
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following code:

```
fun Any.someExtensionFunction() = "Any"
fun String.someExtensionFunction() = "String"

fun main(args: Array<String>) {

    val s = "xyz" // type String inferred

    println(s.someExtensionFunction())
    println((s as Any).someExtensionFunction())
    println((s as String).someExtensionFunction())
}
```

Output:

> String
>   Any
>   String

As you see, the compiler will always call the extension function on the lowest type in the inheritance structure unless explicitely told otherwise.

So, s1m0nw1's answer is correct.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to ensure the `ClosedRange` getter always gets invoked, you can add a check to the `Iterable` getter. Since it is inlined the additional check will probably be optimized away:

```
inline val <T:Comparable<T>> Iterable<T>.max get():T? = when(this) {
    is ClosedRange<*> -> endInclusive //Specific overload for ClosedRange
    else -> max()
}
```